# Making splitter visible for Split Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I make a split panels splitter visible to the user, rather than being invisible with only a cursor change on mouse over?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try setting BorderStyle to Fixed3D

Comment: Simple and fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: What if you don't want a border?

Comment: @rory.ap set the background color of the SplitContainer different from the background color of the panels being split.

Answer (score 75):

This question arises because the `SplitContainer` control has **no direct property** for setting the style of the draggable splitter bar itself.

There are several ways to accomplish this, and even though the other answers posted here work, the one that I share with you below is ultimately the fast, reliable and easiest way.

@BluMonkMN suggested a method using a 3D border, but what if you don't want any border?

@Giles Bathgate suggested adding a Paint event handler that, even though it surely is elegant and does work, comes with a slight performance cost requiring you to add more code to your project that executes at the C# level and may someday become a maintenance issue.

@Philip Fourie suggested changing the `SplitContainer.BackColor` property value; however, that *initially* causes the control's entire background to change color, not just the splitter bar, causing no color contrast.

So, my solution is an enhancement of @Philip Fourie's.

First, I'll mention that the `SplitContainer` actually has two distinct sub-containers, both separated by the splitter bar. These two are represented by the `Panel1` and the `Panel2` properties. Each of them is essentially a Panel container with their own `BackColor` properties, in addition to several other properties.

The `SplitContainer` has *its* own `BackColor` property, making a total of three unique possible colors.

Now, if you were to set this `SplitContainer.BackColor` property, the `Panel1` and `Panel2` "subcontrols" would automatically inherit that color value, and now they'd all be the same, causing NO visual contrast!
This [probably undesirable] property value inheritance only happens when the `Panel1.BackColor` and/or the `Panel2.BackColor` properties have **not yet** been explicitly set by you (even though viewing their property values in the Visual Studio Properties window ahead of time would have revealed "Control.")

Therefore, the order that you set the properties is important:

1. Set both the "child" `Panel1.BackColor` and `Panel2.BackColor` properties to something *other than* the default value of "Control" to force an explicit value (even if you really do want "Control"; we'll fix that later.)
2. Set the "parent" `SplitContainer.BackColor` to the color you desire the splitter bar to be.
3. Finally, go back and set the `Panel1.BackColor` and `Panel2.BackColor` properties to the color you want them to be (perhaps back to "Control".)

And as @Philip Fourie answered, you may wish to set the Width property, actually consistently named `SplitterWidth`, regardless of the [Horizontal vs. Vertical] `Orientation` property.

Here are some useful tips:

While working in the Visual Studio form designer, if you click on the `SplitContainer` on either side of the splitter bar, you'll select *that* `Panel1` or `Panel2` "child" sub-container. But if you click on the splitter bar itself, you'll select the "parent" `SplitContainer`.

And related to what @Stuart Helwig suggested, the default `SplitterWidth` will cause the splitter bar to be outlined when it has focus, thus obscuring the color you selected. Raise the value to `5`, `6`, or higher, which also makes it easier for the end-user to grab & drag.

Finished. Happy Coding!

Comment: Ooh. Creative, and simple. I like it!

Comment: This should be the correct answer, especially since it allows for changing the color of the splitter.  It's also really easy to change the color using this method, despite how long the answer is (due to additional details provided)

Comment: In my case, it was important, to _not_ set the splitter's background color in the c'tor of the using form, but later on in the `Load` handler of the using form.

Answer (score 19):

You could paint your own splitter bar by adding the following event handler to the splitcontainer paint event.

```
private void SplitterPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SplitContainer s = sender as SplitContainer;
    if (s != null) {
        int top = 5;
        int bottom = s.Height - 5;
        int left = s.SplitterDistance;
        int right = left + s.SplitterWidth - 1;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Silver, left, top, left, bottom);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Silver, right, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works when the splitter is oriented vertically, the code could be improved to work regardless of orientation.

Comment: Yep it can be simplified to: `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, s.SplitterRectangle);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use SplitterColor in designer to change splitter border color.

```
public class SplitContainerCustomSplitter : SplitContainer
{
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color SplitterColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
        Rectangle rect = SplitterRectangle;

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(SplitterColor))
        {
            if (Orientation == Orientation.Vertical)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Left, rect.Bottom - 1);
                g.DrawLine(pen, rect.Right - 1, rect.Top, rect.Right - 1, rect.Bottom - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - 1, rect.Top);
                g.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Bottom - 1, rect.Right, rect.Bottom - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or easier:  
pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SplitterColor), SplitterRectangle);

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to change the Splitter's `BackColor` and `Width/Height` properties (depending on the splitter's orientation)

Answer (score 2):

Improved variant of Giles Bathgate's answer:

```cs
private void ds_SplitContainer_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SplitContainer l_SplitContainer = sender as SplitContainer;

    if (l_SplitContainer != null)
    {
        Rectangle ll_ShrinkedSplitterRectangle = l_SplitContainer.SplitterRectangle;
        ll_ShrinkedSplitterRectangle.Offset(0, 2);
        ll_ShrinkedSplitterRectangle.Height = ll_ShrinkedSplitterRectangle.Height - 2;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Silver, ll_ShrinkedSplitterRectangle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick implementation of a horizontal splitter that is filled with a color, has a top and bottom border (similar to Visual Studio splitters), and gripper dots in the middle.

```
    private void splitContainer_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        SplitContainer s = sender as SplitContainer;
        if (s != null)
        {
            int gripLineWidth = 9;
            // Fill Splitter rectangle
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.ControlDark, 
                s.SplitterRectangle.X, s.SplitterDistance, s.SplitterRectangle.Width, s.SplitterWidth);
            // Draw Single Line Border on Top and Bottom
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightSlateGray,
                s.SplitterRectangle.X, s.SplitterDistance, s.SplitterRectangle.Width, s.SplitterDistance);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightSlateGray,
                s.SplitterRectangle.X, s.SplitterDistance + s.SplitterWidth - 1, s.SplitterRectangle.Width, s.SplitterDistance + s.SplitterWidth - 1);
            // Draw gripper dots in center
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(_dashedPen,
                ((s.SplitterRectangle.Width / 2) - (gripLineWidth / 2)),
                s.SplitterDistance + s.SplitterWidth / 2,
                ((s.SplitterRectangle.Width / 2) + (gripLineWidth / 2)),
                s.SplitterDistance + s.SplitterWidth / 2);
        }
    }
```

You can create a Pen as a member variable in the class that performs the drawing which will draw a dotted line in your similar to:

```
private static Pen _dashedPen = new Pen(Color.DarkRed, 1);
_dashedPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
```

Comment: Could you include the code to initialize the dashed pen?

Answer (score 1):

As well as making its BorderStyle Fixed3D as @BlueMonkMN suggested I often find the default SplitterWidth value on the splitContainer object, of 4, is a little narrow.

If you up that to about 6, with a 3D border, it's a little more obvious to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `BackColor` property of the `SplitContainer` to different color. Let say Black. Then each `SpliterPanel`, change its `BackColor` property to different color. Let say White. Then you will notice the SplitLine will become more visible. :)

Comment: This is the same as the answer by GlobalSoftwareSociety

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few of the methods suggested here and not amusing me, I decided to put in a panel1 and in panel2 a thin labels, aligned to the splitter and everything is ok.

```
(label's.Autosize=false, label's.Text = "", label's.Color=SystemColor.Selected,  label1.Dock=left; label2.Dock=right)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement to [GlobalSoftwareSociety's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22888877/621316).

To prevent the panels from inheriting the `BackColor`, it is only needed to write to the property once. You can in fact simply assign the property to itself. This also works for other kinds of controls and similarly inherited properties, like fonts.

Also, to avoid the annoying selection rectangle, make the `SplitContainer` not a tabstop, and activate the first panel on mouse up.

(Need to be careful; at first I tried putting a "tab to next control" call in the `Enter` event, but that prevented all sub controls from ever being activated.)

All together, this makes the fix look something like:

```
splitBox.Panel1.BackColor = splitBox.Panel1.BackColor;
splitBox.Panel2.BackColor = splitBox.Panel2.BackColor;
splitBox.BackColor = yourFavouriteColor;
splitBox.SplitterWidth = yourFavouriteSize;
splitBox.TabStop = false;
splitBox.MouseUp += (s, e) => splitBox.ActiveControl = splitBox.Panel1;
```

Answer (score -1):

The splitter line is visible actually. The real question is it is hard to distinct with other controls.

One idea is to set a new background color to the split container, and make it different with its child panels.

Maybe sometimes we could solve the issue from designer's perspective, not developer's. :-)

Comment: This is the same as the answer by GlobalSoftwareSociety